# React child component unmounting when parent component state is updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am seeing strange behavior that I don't understand in the following code

```
   export class PlayerListPage extends React.Component<PlayerListPageProps, {toggle: boolean}> { 
constructor(props: PlayerListPageProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {           
            toggle: false
        };
    }

    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            toggle: !this.state.toggle
        })
    }



    render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TextField
                        key={1}
                        label={'label'}
                        value={'value'}
                    />
                    <Button
                        onClick={this.handleToggle}
                    >
                        Click
                    </Button>
                </div>

            )
        }
    }
```

Every time this toggle method is triggered, and updates the component's state, the TextField component is unmounted/remounted instead of just re-rendering.

I would expect TextField to re-render without unmounting first. Could somebody kindly point out what I am doing wrong?

Some additional context: here is the parent component (which is the root of the app):

```
@observer
export class RootView extends React.PureComponent {
    private rootStore: RootStore = new RootStore();
    private appTheme : any = createMuiTheme(DarkTheme);    

    @observable private player: Player

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.rootStore.playerStore.retrievePlayerBios();
        this.player = this.rootStore.playerStore.getPlayer('12');
    }

    render() {          
        console.log(this.appTheme);      
        return (
            <main>
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.appTheme}>
                    <Provider rootStore={this.rootStore}>
                        {/* {!!this.player && <PlayerStatsView player={this.player}/>}                     */}
                        <PlayerListPage/>
                    </Provider>
                </MuiThemeProvider>                
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you forgot about creating the state?

Comment: does it still happen if you remove `key={1}`?

Comment: @azium it's a static key, shouldn't cause a re-render

Comment: @kinduser you're right, but nothing else in the code would cause unmounts either, was just curious if that caused odd behaviour. This might not be the actual code?

Comment: Hi guys, I updated the code with additional context. Basic stack uses typescript, React and mobex (except for the example component which just sets state). Also use material ui, but I don't believe that is relevant

Comment: still happens if I remove key={1}